# Error after updating Google Play Services on SDK Mnager

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk, google-play-services

I've create A small Android application with Google Maps Android Api V2, everything works perfectlly so far.
I checked the SDK manager this morning, and I found out that there's an update available for Google Play Services, I installed the updates, re-launched Eclipse and here, Before I Click on anything I have these errors puping up on my Eclipse's Console:

```
[2014-01-18 14:42:23 - GoogleAdsSampleActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-18'
[2014-01-18 14:42:23 - PlusSampleActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2014-01-18 14:42:23 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2014-01-18 14:42:23 - PanoramaSampleActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] Found 2 versions of google-play-services.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] Versions found are:
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] Path: C:\Users\Poox\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1]     Length: 1283446
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1]     SHA-1: 826507592fec9d8e26db18364e709df133c749ce
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] Path: C:\Users\Poox\Desktop\JAVA\AndTestMap1\libs\google-play-services.jar
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1]     Length: 959413
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1]     SHA-1: cebe8e4a3a469c4623addcca1dc571407ff3a08e
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] Found 2 versions of google-play-services.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] Versions found are:
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] Path: C:\Users\Poox\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1]     Length: 1283446
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1]     SHA-1: 826507592fec9d8e26db18364e709df133c749ce
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] Path: C:\Users\Poox\Desktop\JAVA\AndTestMap1\libs\google-play-services.jar
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1]     Length: 959413
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1]     SHA-1: cebe8e4a3a469c4623addcca1dc571407ff3a08e
[2014-01-18 14:42:24 - AndTestMap1] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

And All my projects using the Google Maps Android V2 have a Exclamation Mark next to them in my project browser in Eclipse. And when I try to run my prject nothing happen, excpet for this window telling me that my project has errors that I should fix, I checked it many times, not a single error. What is going on exaclty? 
My code: 
Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Poox2.andtestmap4"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Poox2.andtestmap4.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDmVLuYyZcerTxTlyGbHpxedvGenUxukhA"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can you please tell me what's going on and how to fix this? meanwhile i'm checking around for it.

Comment: first replace your android-support-libs form google-play-services_lib project

Answer (score 0):

The error log tells you exactly what the problem is: your project is referencing two different versions of the play lib, the old one and the new one.

It seems like you have a .jar file of the play library in your lib folder and referenced the the play library project at the same time. One of them is the older version and has to be removed.